# How to fix flex spacing from two separate classes

Tags: html, css

I have two separate classes  in my gallery box container. I've set it to use a flex display, however there is no spacing in the column. Plus, It's not showing all of the pictures as well as the text.

I've messed around with a few of the justify-content attributes, but that hasn't seemed to work. I've also tried messing around with the classes with no luck.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <h1>Gallery Mockup</h1>
    <div id="content">

        <!-- put your card HTML here -->
        <div class="card">
            <div id="workplease">
                <button onclick="contract_gallery()" type="button" id="close_gallery" style="display:none" align="left">&times; Close</button>
                <center>                    
                    <h2>Gallery Mockup</h2>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="gallerybox" class="inactive">


                <img class="pic" id="pic1" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400">
                <img class="pic" id="pic2" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400" style="display:none">
                <div class="inactive" id="gtext">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat pellentesque lacus, sit amet sodales tellus porttitor sed. Donec mattis lectus in hendrerit mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis id est vitae leo viverra egestas. Donec commodo, mauris ut sagittis commodo, erat erat tristique metus, at faucibus quam arcu eu metus. Duis eget metus eu arcu porttitor venenatis nec sed nibh. Sed eleifend efficitur orci. Suspendisse eu felis vitae sem varius fringilla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer a molestie felis, non ultricies mi. Proin facilisis commodo nisi id fermentum. Ut porttitor molestie rhoncus. Curabitur tempus volutpat mauris, eu dignissim mauris viverra quis.</p>
                    <p>Donec elementum vestibulum felis, ac commodo erat commodo a. Aenean in felis scelerisque justo ornare gravida et sed massa. Etiam in venenatis neque, accumsan volutpat sapien. Sed molestie nisl sem, ac fringilla mauris dignissim nec. Sed placerat ut elit vitae convallis. Donec iaculis efficitur tincidunt. Suspendisse mollis ut orci at maximus. Sed consectetur diam a mauris consectetur, eu sodales purus sollicitudin. Pellentesque quis tellus id est venenatis pharetra fringilla quis libero. Praesent semper, odio eu consectetur malesuada, enim felis euismod eros, in aliquam leo mi non est. Nam ornare scelerisque nisi nec gravida.</p>
                </div>
                <img class="pic" id="pic3" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400" style="display:none">
                <img class="pic" id="pic4" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400" style="display:none">
                <img class="pic" id="pic5" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400" style="display:none">
                <img class="pic" id="pic6" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400" style="display:none">
                <img class="pic" id="pic7" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400" style="display:none">
                <img class="pic" id="pic8" src="https://picsum.photos/230/400" style="display:none">


            </div>
            <center>
                <button type="button" id="gbutton" onclick="expand_gallery()">See Gallery</button>
            </center>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/final-frontier.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 490px) {
    #gallerybox.active {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

When the width of the screen goes below 490px, it's supposed to go to flex view, and it does, however there is no spacing in between the photos, and it's not showing all of them. This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQjfQ.png

Comment: Your current code says `<img ... style="display:none">`, unless the script `<script src="js/final-frontier.js"></script>` takes care of that, you will never see those images appear...

Comment: Another thing, friendly piece of advice: if you cannot create a simple logical structure in a HTML document it is not recommended to start using Javascript. It just gets more complicated and draws your attention away from a sound HTML structure. For what I can see, you don't need JS to get a working 'card'.

Comment: try to disable the rest of the CSS and see if the flex is working fine. It works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/24ztcnh7/)

Answer (score 1):

Your best options would be to wrap your images in div's and use `Flexbox` accordingly. This approach always works for me and I would recommend it:

Your Html

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="item">
        <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src=""/>
</div>
```

Your Css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 490px) {
    .flexbox  {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        width: 100%; //take full width
    }

    .item img {
        width: 100%; //set 100% width
        height: auto; //auto height adjustment
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried all of the justiy-content values, but none of them have fixed my issue.